# How do I add multiple adapters and listeners to one class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am a bit of a newbie to programming in general. I am working my way through a few tutorials but currently a bit stuck.

The code below is for a simple app using lists. But how do I go about adding a second adpapter/listener for another option within the list? I am slightly puzzled where to place it and the answer does not seem to be hitting me in the face even though it is probably simple.

```
public class TopLevelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_level);
//Create an OnItemClickListener
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int 
position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TopLevelActivity.this, 
                ChestCategoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    };
    //Add the listener to the list view
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_options);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't.  See the position parameter to onItemClick?  It tells you which item was clicked.  See how you have if(position==0)?  You'd also have an if(position==1), if position==2, etc. Or more likely use a switch statement.